# Parse Swift PFFacebookUtils missing

Tags: swift, facebook, parse-platform

does anybody know where the PFFacebookUtils framework is? or where I can download it from. It gives me the error "no such module" when I to import the PFFacebookUtils framework and I cant find it anywhere in the files on my computer

Answer (score 0):

You can download PFFacebookUtils from https://parse.com/docs/downloads under SDK. The zip file you download contains PFFacebookUtils.